# heredoc failing when piped into ssh

Tags: bash, tcsh

I am trying to do commands via ssh using a heredoc.  when I use the 'EOF' style:

```
result=$(ssh $quiet -T ${G_IPAddressBase}${G_TGP} <<- 'EOF'
set pid=`ps -ef | grep TestPatterns | egrep -v 'grep|tail|vi|csh' | gawk '{print $2}'`
if ( "$pid" != "" ) then
        echo "TestPatterns ($pid) terminated"
        kill $pid
else
        echo "TestPatterns down already"
endif
EOF
)
```

everything works as excepted because the $ and qrave marks are not expanded out.

But if I want to include local variables and use \ to stop the variable from being resolved, the \ does not stop the $ variable from resolving as expected.

```
result=$(ssh $quiet -T ${G_IPAddressBase}${G_TGP} <<- EOF
set pid=\`ps -ef | grep $mytaskName | grep '\/bin\/bash' | gawk '{print \$2}'\`
if ( "\$pid" == "" ) then
        echo "ERROR: $mytaskName cored"
else
        if ( -f "$mytaskLogpath" ) then
                set agent1Done=1
        else
                echo "ERROR:  $mytaskName didn't make a report file"
        endif
endif
EOF
)
```

The pid is being set to blank because its looks like this on the remote side:

```
set pid=`ps -ef | grep TestPatterns | egrep -v 'grep|tail|vi|csh' | gawk '{print }'`
```

Everything that I have read says this should not be happening.  If I  `cat << EOF > /tmp/command.csh` the heredoc to a file the commands match what I expect on the remote box and work as expected.

This script is in bash, but the default shell is tcsh and that's what the remote is running so its not because the csh commands are running in a bash window on the remote login.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you considered passing arguments on the shell command line instead of inband inside the program text? That way you'd be able to keep using `<<'-EOF'`

Comment: Is there any possibility of putting the code into a script that you copy to the server and then execute?

Comment: How is `grep '\/bin\/bash'` turning into `egrep -v 'grep|tail|vi|csh'`?

Comment: BTW, that's a pretty nasty command line. I'd consider making it `ps -ef | gawk '/TestPatterns/ && ! /grep|tail|vi|csh/ { print $2 }'` -- no reason to use four separate components when two will do.

Comment: BTW, there's no need to escape `/` in `grep`.

Comment: Does the remote system have a `pgrep` command so you don't need to code that yourself?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you need to change it to `! /awk|csh/`

Comment: the task the I am greping for via ps -ef is a bash script and so the ps line is /usr/bash/agent.sh so that's not the problem.  As I said if I cat the heredoc to a file and ssh it over and then ssh run it, it works fine.

Comment: Again the problem is the $ stuff disappearing, not the syntax of the commands.